# Question with work and Spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, spring

Hey so im currently going through questions and I've become confused on this question.

[image: Question]

I was able to get an answer a different way, finding the x value by equating F = kx and solving for x, and then setting the equation up.

(1/2)(800)(0.1)^2 = (1/2)(800)(0.03)^2 + (1/2)(10)(v^2)
and then solving for V

Sorry, I don't know how to write equations properly.

And I got the same answer as the solution, however, Im confused on why they can equation the work the force does, to the potential energy of the spring + kinetic. is there a formula for this? Cause I only recall W = -(PE).

Comment: "I was able to get an answer a different way, finding the x value by equating F = kx and solving for x" why do you say you need to find x? Don't they give it as 13cm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was able to get an answer a different way, finding the x value by
> equating F = kx and solving for x, and then setting the equation up.

Don't understand what you mean by finding "x". It's given to you as 13 cm.

> Im confused on why they can equation the work the force does, to the
> potential energy of the spring + kinetic. is there a formula for this?

They're using the work energy theorem which states that the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy, or

$$W_{net}=\Delta KE$$

The applied constant force $P$ does positive work of $Px$ since its force acts in the same direction as the displacement $x$. The spring does negative work of $-\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ because its restoring force is in the opposite direction of the displacement. The net work is the algebraic sum of the two. That equals the change in kinetic energy of the block, or

$$W_{net}=Px-\frac{1}{2}kx^{2}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

> Cause I only recall W = -(PE).

What you are recalling is the work done only by conservative forces. In this case, it is the elastic force done by the spring, $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Just one thing, by displacement you mean from the equilibrium position with displacement moving to the right correct? and by finding x, I was trying to find the amount the string stretches when a force of P is applied on to it, which i got 0.1m for.

Comment: @Garish19 correct on both points. Keep in mind, however, that P is applied to the block,  not the spring. The restoring force of the spring depends only on its displacement